# Flutter: How to make a Widget off screen

Tags: flutter, dart

TL;DR How can I offset a widget so that it is off screen (not visible but very close to the edge)?

I have a multi page flutter app with some pages that have a floating action button and some that don't. I don't want it to fade in but rather slide in.

What I have done to achieve this is having a normal floatingActionButton on pages that do have a floating action button and have floating action button's wrapped in a `Transform.translate()` to move them to the edge of the screen. When routing, the Hero widget which is already in the floating action button animates it for me. I set the offset to be `offset: Offset(((width / 6) > 56 ? width / 6 : 60) + (width / 428), 0)` but the problem is that it looks fine on the iPhone 12 Pro Max emulator but on smaller screens I can still see some of the FAB. How can I make sure that the FAB is not visible and is on the edge of the screen? I don't want offset it by the width of the screen as the FAB would move out of the screen too quickly to cover the distance so I wan't it to be very close to the edge of the screen (a few logical pixels off screen). How can I do this?

Thank you for your help!

**Edit:**

Here's what I currently have, I want it to work with other screen sizes (smaller ones in particular)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WzPnvsM6mMQYS1qSuuG0RpZq1c2o3mY5/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to make sure the widget is totally off the screen on every device is to use the width from `MediaQuery`:

```
Transform.translate(
 offset: Offset(
  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  0.0,
 ),
 child: ...
),
```

There is also a `FractionalTranslation` widget. It accepts a `translation` property which is an `Offset`. If you want to make a widget be translated 100% of the screen to the right you would do this:

```
...
FractionalTranslation(
 translation: Offset(1.0, 0.0),
 child: Text('Lorem ipsum'),
)
...
```

This is a great solution, however as of the time of writing this it doesn't work when used with a `FloatingActionButton`. When the `translation` is set to `Offset(1.0, 0.0)` a little part of the `FloatingActionButton` is still visible. This might be an issue in the framework that will be fixed in the future.

To get around this you could build your own `FloatingActionButton` using a `Stack` widget.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already tried this and I don't want to just set it to the width as it moves too fast so the animation isn't really visible and is only seen for like a few frames. Is there another way, even if it is a bit more complicated?

Comment: Well, you can slow down the animation. No matter what way you move the widget off screen the animation will be the same.

Comment: I edited the original post to show what I currently have, I want that to work on multiple screens.

I can't slow down the animation of the Hero alone because I am pushing another page as a replacement and I don't want to the transition between pages to take ages because that might frustrate a lot of people if they have to wait 5 seconds just to change pages.

Comment: Do you have to use a `Hero`? And can you post a full screen recording?

Comment: I really don't want to use animations to animate the position to be off screen as I am already doing that for the rotation of the icon and that was janky enough. I feel adding more containers would make the page really hard to work on in the future as changes would be difficult to make and the code might not be as readable as a floating action button widget that's just centred off screen.

Comment: Here's a link to the full screen recording https://cln.sh/alvWTz. I also have test containers wrapped in `Hero()`s (blue and red containers) as I was testing something earlier and I think using a Hero would be the best approach if I can figure out a way to centre the fab to be just off screen.

Comment: I did a little research and I found out about the `FractionalTranslation` widget. It might be just what you need, however as of know it doesn't work with the `FloatingActionButton`. Check out my answer. You should maybe submit an issue on Flutter's GitHub.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232825/discussion-between-andrej-and-hady).

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has an [Offstage widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Offstage-class.html), I think it's made for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your help, where is the widget located when it is 'offstage'? is it just moved over to be on the edge of the screen or is it just hidden? As I don't just want to move the widget off screen but I want to have the Hero animate it's position.

Comment: Aw, right, now that I see the video I understand better what your problem is. I think Offstage is not the right solution in that case, as it doesn't position it anywhere, but simply 'keeps it off the stage'.